# Integer dividers

Tags: php, laravel, math

I have array like this:

```
[
 [
  'minutes': 60
 ]
 [
  'minutes': 600
 ],
 [
 'minutes': 1440
 ]
]
```

And from response getting integer like `720`

I need to split 720 with using my array
For example:

```
[
  '600' => 1,
  '60'  => 2,
]
```

So 60*2 + 600 = 720

Updated, but $_rate / 10 is incorrect. Maybe i dont need to use % in calculations

```
public function calculate($_rate, $minutes, $results)
    {
        if(empty($results))
        {
            dump(['rate' => $_rate, 'minutes' => $minutes, 'remainder' => $minutes % $_rate]);
            if(($minutes % $_rate) == 0)
                return ['rate' => $_rate, 'count' => $minutes / $_rate];
            elseif(($minutes % $_rate) != 0) {
                return [
                    $this->calculate($_rate/10, ($minutes % $_rate), $results),
                    [
                        'rate' => $minutes - ($minutes % $_rate), 'count' => $minutes / $minutes - ($minutes % $_rate)
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Show your current efforts.

Comment: Im stucked with recursive. And its cause iam asking here.

Comment: @Andrew, Your question is not clear. What do you mean by first array? Did you want a result `720` from second array only?

Comment: Seems like a simple task. What have you tried?

Comment: Iam trying to do it with %  `if(($minutes % $_rate) == 0)
                return ['rate' => $_rate, 'count' => $minutes / $_rate];
            elseif(($minutes % $_rate) != 0) {
                return [
                    $this->calculate($_rate/10, ($minutes % $_rate), $results),
                    [
                        'rate' => $minutes - ($minutes % $_rate), 'count' => $minutes / $minutes - ($minutes % $_rate)
                    ]
                ];
            }` but $_rate/10 already incorrect. im stucked on this Maybe i have incorrect logic for implementation

Comment: @MH2K9 first array with data of minutes. Response with integer. I need to split this integer to sum of deviders from first array and add to second with multiplier

Comment: @Andrew Please don't put additional information in comments. Edit your question and add the code.

Comment: @chrisis sorry, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different loops like in this code:

```
$array = [
    [
     'minutes'=> 60
    ],
    [
     'minutes'=> 600
    ],
    [
    'minutes'=> 1440
    ]
    ];

$response = 720;
$remain = $response;
$result = [];

while ($remain > 0) {
    for ($i = count($array)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
        $result["{$array[$i]['minutes']}"] = 0;
        while ($remain >= $array[$i]['minutes']) {
            $result["{$array[$i]['minutes']}"]++;
            $remain -= $array[$i]['minutes'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will fail if the number is not even with array values. https://3v4l.org/q8Uqq

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop and compare largest values first.
Subtract if $n is larger than minutes value.
The use array_count_values to get how many 600 and 60 minutes you need.

```
$arr =array_reverse($arr);
$n =720;
$res=array();
Foreach($arr as $val){
    While($n >= $val['minutes']){
        $res[] = $val['minutes'];
        $n -= $val['minutes'];
    }
    If($n == 0) break;
}
$res =array_count_values($res);
$res[$n] = 1; // optional if you want to capture remaining after loop.
Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/1mlIX
Or if you want to capture remaining:
https://3v4l.org/6Y7CC

Outputs

```
array(2) {
     [600] => 1
     [60] => 2
}
```